# No NgModule metadata found for 'DynamicTestModule' in unit test

Tags: angular, typescript

Using `Angular2.0.0-rc.5` I am attempting to run the following test but receiving the error:

> Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'DynamicTestModule'. (line 29)

This `DynamicTestModule` appears to be part of angular itself and is not a module I have reference in my project or can find in the Docs page on [angular.io](http://angular.io)

```
import {inject, async, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

describe('AuthService', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
            BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
            platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
        ).configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                {ngModule: CommonModule, providers: [
                    ... // overrides for testing
                ]}
            ]});
    });

    it('should get and set a token saved in storage', inject([AuthService], (instance: AuthService) => {
        instance.token = 'test-token';
        expect(instance.token).toEqual('test-token');
    }));
});
```

Searching google for the error message returns no results, and their changelog does not mention this in the example.

Has anyone seen this specific error and know what is going on, or could you provide an example of testing a service in `2.0.0-rc.5` using the built in DI that does not have this resulting error?

Comment: [There's no sign that a module](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgModuleMetadata-class.html#!#imports-anchor) can be a plain object here. Something like `{ imports: [CommonModule], providers: [...] }` should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @estus The `imports` statement takes an `Array<Type | ModuleWithProviders | any[]>`. I am passing in a [`ModuleWithProviders`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ModuleWithProviders-interface.html) so the syntax is valid.

Answer (score 2):

If you using SystemJS module loader to load angular modules, you should use individual files, not bundles.

After loading SystemJS in your index file

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

and before loading systemjs.config.js from [quickstart application](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#config-files)

```
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

you need to set

```
<script>System.packageWithIndex = true;</script>
```

Comment: In my case the systemjs.config.js wasn't checking the packageWithIndex flag, but switching from "bundled" to "individual files" (which was commented out) fixed the issue.

Comment: wait, why do you "need" to set it? I don't see it used in places where systemjs is used such as https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Latest Angular version is 2.0.0. Answer is related to 2.0.0-rc.5

Comment: [systemjs.config.js with packageWithIndex setting](https://plnkr.co/edit/VcHbK2YaQQ29i2Q9vupw)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue:

```
SCRIPT5022: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.
```

For me, [this angular2 issue comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7144#issuecomment-190012839) fixed the issues regarding various IE versions (especially IE10).